# Changes to code in com.android.library Module in AndroidStudio not being applied

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Whenever I make code changes to a library module in AndroidStudio they are not applied while installing the app unless I **rebuild** the project. I use a default 'app' configuration to run the project. It is time consuming and makes my work very inefficient. I've tried the same project on two different computers, both running AS 3.0 alpha 9.

Main Project:

app gradle: `implementation project (':qlm')`

settings.gradle:

```
 include ':app' 

 include ':qlm' project(':qlm').projectDir = new
   File(settingsDir, '../QlmReader/qlm')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly this problem has been solved by enabling Instant Run.